# Associated Library in QTP not working

Tags: functional-testing, qtp

I am new to QTP, just started using it. I have written one class definition in some functional library and also created a test as under:

```
Class ExcelFileReader
Public default Function Init(pathToExcel)
   Dim objFSO
   Dim result
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   If objFSO.FileExists(pathToExcel) Then
            Rem File Found
            Dim objExcel
            Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            objExcel.Workbooks.open(pathToExcel)

       Else
            REM File not found
            result = vbOk
            While result <> vbCancel
                result = Msgbox ("Unable to Locate the file", 5, "Error")
            Wend
            ExitAction(1)
       End If
End Function
```

End Class

Test:

```
 Dim objExcelReader : Set objExcelReader = New ExcelFileReader
objExcelReader.Init("D:\mytest.xlsx")
```

I have associated the functional library with the test but still I am getting an error at line number 2 in test stating class definition not found. Also if I copy complete code in the same file "test" then the things are working as intended.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes have local scope in your library. You have to construct them with a public function to make them publicly available:

```
Public Function new_ExcelFileReader()
    Set new_ExcelFileReader = new ExcelFileReader
End Function

Class ExcelFileReader
    Sub Class_Initialize
        MsgBox "Present!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

And in your other library:

```
Dim objExcelReader : Set objExcelReader = New_ExcelFileReader
objExcelReader.Init("D:\mytest.xlsx")
```

Protip: You can pass initialization parameters into your constructor function.

**EDIT**

On request: how to pass constructor parameters. Just add them to your constructor function:

```
Public Function new_ExcelFileReader2(filepath, sheetname)
    Set new_ExcelFileReader2 = new ExcelFileReader
    new_ExcelFileReader2.Init(filepath, sheetname)
End Function

' And the call:
Set myExcelFileReader = new_ExcelFileReader2("C:\temp\tempExcel.xlsx", "sheet1")
```

In my implementation I have sometimes the same object, but that gets 'configured' by multiple contructor functions. In your case you could have a `new_ExcelFileReader`, a `new_CSVFileReader` and a `new_TabDelimitedReader` all pointing to the same object but configured differently.

Another way to fancy up your code is to return the object (with the `me` keyword) by the init function. This will result in code like this:

```
Class ExcelFileReader

    private filepath_
    public function Init(filepath)
        filepath_ = filepath
        Set Init = me
    end function

End Class

Set myExcelFileReader = new ExcelFileReader.Init("C:\temp\tmpExcel.xlsx")
```

With a constructor function you can use it by just returning the object and then calling the `Init` function.

```
Public Function new_ExcelFileReader()   ' this is the same as the first function
    Set new_ExcelFileReader = new ExcelFileReader
End Function

Set myExcelFileReader = new_ExcelFileReader.Init("C:\temp\tmpExcel.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hi AutomatedChaos, thanks that worked. As you suggested, Could you please tell me how to create parameterized constructors, I tried but was not able to do that.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Couldn't he just make the Class public?

Comment: @TheBlastOne no, you cannot make a class public (like `Public Class YadaYada`) as you could do with a function, sub or variable. Not in QTP at least.